# ASP.NET MVC 5 PRG pattern with multiple modals

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, post-redirect-get

I am implementing a register form using a modal. The users enter their information, it posts to UserController/Register action with RegisterViewModel. Once the user account is successfully created, the register modal is replaced by a profile modal that collects additional user information, which posts to UserController/Profile actions with ProfileViewModel.

Currently my solution is to Ajax post the form and upon success display the next modal, but that's not the PRG pattern.

I would like to use Post-Redirect-Get pattern, but if I redirect after submitting the registration form, it will reload the page instead of showing Profile Modal. How do I implement PRG pattern with multiple modals showing one after the other? What if the form had more than 2 steps?

Comment: Not the exact same, but similar to what you're asking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/715447/how-do-i-create-a-concise-and-restful-wizard-under-mvc - hopefully the second answer on that question can provide some insights?

Comment: That's a very helpful question. But my problem is not REST exactly. I already dont' have ?step=2 etc. My problem is to implement PRG.

Comment: Applying REST principles here, in my opinion, would help you apply PRG, and more importantly, how to manage the _state transfer_.

Comment: PRG is fundamentally incompatible with using AJAX. The whole point of PRG is that you *redirect*. AJAX involves no redirects. Just follow REST principles as @Smudge202 suggests and don't worry about PRG.